# Reusing path in multiple MATCH UNION queries cypher neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'd like to pull and combine data from several different paths that share a path at the beginning, not all of which might exist. For example, I'd like to do something like this:

```
MATCH (:Complex)-[:PATH]->(s:Somewhere)-[:FETCHING]->(data)
    RETURN data.attribute
UNION ALL
MATCH (s)-[:OPTIONAL]->(o:OtherData)
    RETURN o.attribute;
```

so that it doesn't retrace the path up to s. I can't actually do this, though, because UNION separates queries and the (s)-[:OPTIONAL] in the second part will match anything with an outgoing OPTIONAL relation; the s is a loose handle.

Is there a better way of doing this than repeating the path:

```
MATCH (:Complex)-[:PATH]->(s:Somewhere)-[:FETCHING]->(data)
    RETURN data.attribute
UNION ALL
MATCH (:Complex)-[:PATH]->(s:Somewhere)-[:OPTIONAL]->(o:OtherData)
    RETURN o.attribute;
```

I made a few attempts using WITH, but they all either caused the query to return nothing if any part failed, or I could not get them to line up into a single column and instead got rows with redundant data, or (with multiple, nested WITHs, which I'm not sure about the scoping of) just fetching everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at the semantics of an optional match? So you can match to s, beyond s and your optional component. Something like:

```
MATCH (:Complex)-[:PATH]->(s:Somewhere)
MATCH (s)-[:FETCHING]->(data)
OPTIONAL MATCH (s)-[:OPTIONAL]->(otherData)
RETURN data.attribute, otherData.attribute
```

Sorry I missed the importance of a single column, is it really important?

You can gather the vaues into a single *collection* :

```
MATCH (:Complex)-[:PATH]->(s:Somewhere)
MATCH (s)-[:FETCHING]->(data)
OPTIONAL MATCH (s)-[:OPTIONAL]->(otherData)
RETURN [data.attribute] + COLLECT(otherData.attribute)
```

But doesn't this work for a single column:

```
MATCH (:Complex)-[:PATH]->(s:Somewhere)
MATCH (s)-[:FETCHING]->(data)
OPTIONAL MATCH (s)-[:OPTIONAL]->(otherData)
WITH [data.attribute] + COLLECT(otherData.attribute) as col
RETURN UNWIND col AS val
```

Comment: That doesn't line things up into one column. If there's only one match for data, and many for otherData, I'll get a 2-column result with the same data.attribute in the left for each otherData.attribute in the right. The type of data is the same for the two, so I'm trying to get a single column, like my example query gives.

Comment: Your syntax doesn't exactly work, but I can kinda get it to work with:

`
MATCH (:Complex)-[:PATH]->(s:Somewhere)
MATCH (s)-[:FETCHING]->(data)
OPTIONAL MATCH (s)-[:OPTIONAL]->(otherData)
WITH [data.attribute] + COLLECT(otherData.attribute) as col
UNWIND col AS val
RETURN val;
`

It gives nulls which need to be eliminated, but it's not bad. In the end, I think the UNION is the way to go, it'd just be nice to be able to save references and have an inner scope which can reference them, so I could do the top match, then have an inner query that references it in each part of the UNION. Thanks!

Comment: Great, but I don't understand where your NULL values are coming from - I'm assuming all the above are theoretical queries but I don't think there should be any nulls. However, if there are, you can use Filter to get rid of them. http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-functions-collection.html#functions-filter